# .NET WCF 4.5 Security - Cross-domain access through jQuery

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-security

I understand this is quite a common problem, but I've been reading so many tutorials that haven't *quite* covered what I'm needing, I felt it'd be best to ask a question here.

What I'm trying to do, simply, is create a WCF 4.5 Service and create authorization on it so that only the users with the correct authorization can access it, in which I'm wanting access through jQuery requests also.

I've followed a tutorial and locked my service down and using Basic Auth, but then the tutorial persists in using a base 64 encoded string on the client machine and sending that through the request header (in which I'm sure can actually be seen in Firebug?!) - so this could, in theory, be decoded quite easily by a hacker? Would SSL make this request header unreadable in Firebug?

Also, I've added the Access-Control-Allow-Origin to my Global.asax service and the Authorization header isn't being picked up in my service at all, so I'm not too sure what's happening there - if this even worked, is it CORS and so would this method not work for IE6?

Apologies to some for my complete lack of understanding on this, but it's proving to be a minefield of information!